# Python last positional argument method call

Tags: python, arguments

I am used to use `*_` to pass arguments I don't care about to methods, for example:

```
def fun(a, *_):
   pass
```

So that `fun` can be called with any number of positional parameters while I only retain the first one.

Is there a symmetric possibility of using only the last one? Something like

```
def fun(*_, a):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, in python 3 there is:

```
def fun(*_, a):
    print(_)
    print(a)

fun(1, 2, 3, a=4)
```

note that this way you are forced to use `a` as a keyword argument (and specify `a=...` in any case). `f(4)` will not work. `f(a=4)` will.

and that is exactly what this can be used for: to force keyword-only arguments.

this is the corresponding PEP: [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).